# Pass an array of objects and an ID, Javascript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have an array of objects and an id, I would like to send it thorough an $http post and in the back end save them in two variables.
Students is an array of object of students, each one with some properties.

JavaScript:

```
$scope.students = []; // This is the array of objects

$http({
  url: 'api/students',
  method: 'POST',
  params:{
    id: classId,
    students: $scope.students
  }
})
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MethodName(int id, List<Student> students){
  //TODO
}
```

I would like to send it and catch that two things in the backend.

Comment: `params` is get, just use [`$http.post( url, data )`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Comment: So the data will be something likes this: `data: { id: classId, students: $scope.students}` ?